# iOS Framework Concept: QR Code Scanning

Tags: ios, frameworks, qr-code

I have been reading [framework](http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios) [tutorial](http://www.meonbinary.com/2013/07/creating-universal-ios-framework) as I need to separate UI and implementation by packaging implementation into framework. I am struggling to grab the concept.

For example I need to create a QR framework, when I click a button, it will launch the QR page > Catch the text string > Populate it into a label.

From the code in [appCoda](http://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-ios-programming-tutorial/), how to I separate the UI? How's about the camera screen view(code in UI/Framework)?

Can frameworks include other frameworks?

**Updated**
I am trying to get my hands on the QR but merging the framework with the QR.

I am getting error:

```
NSBundle </var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/5B97C76C-06E0-4E5A-821C-502477239962/UIControlDevApp.app/RWUIControls.bundle> (not yet loaded)
```

At this line

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"RWUIControls" withExtension:@"bundle"]];
```

I have included my source code in [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fk6ia5m2adpopw0/UIControlDevApp.zip?dl=0).

Answer (score 2):

Hang in there and keep re-reading the tutorials.  They are pretty meaty and take a bit of effort.  Frameworks are great and worth the effort.  Especially for something like the scanner that you will use again and again.

Yes frameworks can contain other frameworks and they can as well and....

When you create the framework you will end up with two output files.  The framework itself as well as a bundle that contains your resources (this is the storyboard and image files.)

You will need to add both of these to the project you want to use them in.

First initialize an instance of your framework by referencing it whatever initializer you have created and supply the bundle name so it can find the resources.

In your framework you can use delegation to return the string that is decoded.  Register the instance of your class in the main app (the one you just initialized) to receive delegate messages from your framework.

Finally push the view controller from your framework onto the stack for display within your main application.

```
 self.qrScanner = [[QRScanner alloc] initWithBundleName:@"QRSCanner.bundle" navigationControllerRequired:NO];
self.qrScanner.delegate = self;
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(pushCustomViewController:)])
{
[self.delegate pushCustomViewController:self.qrScanner.qrScannerMainViewController];
}
```

This is is short code sample of what those three steps look like.  Assuming you have created the framework and bundle this will allow you to reference them from your main application.

Comment: Thank you. Your words give me some comfort to continue. May I know what is the type of qrScanner? Is it a view or a viewController(with xib)?

Comment: qrScanner would be the framework you create.  Create it as a view controller with a storyboard.  In the storyboard, the view for your scanning overlay screen would be "qrScannerMainViewController" in the Storyboard ID field of the Identity section.  Said another way - to reference the various views within your storyboard use the name you assign in the Identiy/Storyboard Id field.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Soccer. I have grasp a bit of how to proceed but I am stuck at the stage to present my screen as I am getting nib not loaded thus no screen in the framework is showed.  I  have attached my code, can you help me to see if I have did any mistake?https://www.dropbox.com/s/fk6ia5m2adpopw0/UIControlDevApp.zip?dl=0

Comment: You are missing a target.  I can see that you have used a little bit from Ray Wenderlich but not sure what.  This is an excellent tutorial that his team created.  http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios  From your project I don't see where you included your created framework.  When you create a framework you will have two output items - the bundle with the resources and the framework that contains the code that is run.  In creating the framework you will have a workspace that contains multiple projects.  There is a sample project to go with the tutorial that should help

Comment: I have two inputs when I run the project as output at desktop. It has included the bundle and framework as intructed from the tutorial. Is my view controller calling ok?

Comment: this is the link to the complete framework and bundle. the project produce framework when I build the framework in the static library. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0hychsidfzbji11/AABGPmfWT5CRZ06dAV-Hryhna?dl=0